# How to copy one file to multiple folder with wildcard OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, cp

I am trying to use terminal to copy a file from one destination to multiple destinatons using wildcard for username (every username is 2 digits and 6 letters)

```
cp -R /file.plist /Users/????????/Library/Preferences/
```

The problem is that the file copyes to one of the users but not the others.
And it seems like it is copying everything from one of the users to the other.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for d in /Users/*; do cp /file.plist "$d/Library/Preferences"; done
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! But when i tried to do copy inside a folder with space in the name something got wrong.

`for d in /System/Library/User\ Template/*; do cp /file.plist $d/Library/Preferences; done`

Any suggestions?

Comment: @lobirkeland That should be fixed now (answer edited).  See [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html).